# Find a sequence of identical characters in a string (C)

Tags: c, string, loops

My goal is to write a function that checks the input string for a sequence of identical characters. For example with the inputs:

```
aaah
hey
and
foo
```

the program should print out:

```
The string contains a sequence
The string does not contain a sequence
The string does not contain a sequence
The string contains a sequence
```

since **aaah** contains the sequence 'aaa' and **foo** contains the sequence 'oo'. The code I came up with, however, only prints out **The string does not contain a sequence**, no matter what I input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

int seqCount (char inp[])
{
    int countChar = 0;
    int seqExists = FALSE;
    for(int i = 0; inp[i] != '\0'; i++){

        if(inp[i] == inp[i+1]){

            countChar++;
        }
        else{
            continue;
        }
    }
    if (countChar > 0)
    {
        seqExists = TRUE;
    }
    else{
       seqExists = FALSE;
    }
    return seqExists;



}
int main ()
{
    char inp[100];
    printf("Enter the string: \n");
    scanf("%d", &inp);
    if(seqCount(inp)){

        printf("The string contains a sequence.\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("The string does not contain a sequence.\n");
    }


    return 0;
}
```

I don't know if the whole approach is wrong, or there is some kind of a more subtle mistake.

Comment: `scanf("%d", &inp);` --> `scanf("%99s", inp);`. `inp` is an array of `char`s, you can not fill the array using the `%d` (useful for `int`s) format specifier.

Comment: `else{
            continue;
        }` is not required

Comment: `seqCount` is also an improper name since you don't return the count. If you don't need the count, just make it `bool hasSequence(const char *inp) { for(int i = 0; inp[i] != '\0'; i++) if(inp[i] == inp[i+1]) return true; return false; }` - Note that you don't need to define your own `bool`eans, `TRUE` and `FALSE`. Just `#include <stdbool.h>` and use `true` and `false`.

Comment: Thank you all. You helped me a lot. Both with the problem itself and with the overall cleanness of the code. :)

Comment: You posted a question "Find identical substrings of N lenght (C)" and then deleted it -- this is a three dimensional search, you need three nested loops, the number of characters `n`, `[substringLen, inpLen / 2]`, and two substrings. Since the are symmetric, _wlog_ you can order them `a`, `b`, but `n` affects `a` and `b`. Use `memcmp` from `string.h`.